# NewtonSoft JSON Deserialize results in still serialized data

Tags: c#, json

I receive a GET request response from a REST API, in a string.  As received, it looks like this:

```
[
    {\"passport_expiration\": \"2019-09-14\", \"first_name\": \"asdfasdf\", \"last_name\": \"asdfasdf\", \"cass_status\": \"APPROVED\", \"notes\": null, \"kcm_status\": \"DENIED\", \"employment_type\": \"flight_deck\", \"employee_id\": \"10556\", \"passport_id\": \"12341234\"}, 
    {\"passport_expiration\": \"2026-01-04\", \"first_name\": \"asdfasdf\", \"last_name\": \"asdfasdf\", \"cass_status\": \"APPROVED\", \"notes\": null, \"kcm_status\": \"DENIED\", \"employment_type\": \"flight_deck\", \"employee_id\": \"10557\", \"passport_id\": \"12341234\"}, 
    {\"passport_expiration\": \"2026-08-31\", \"first_name\": \"asdfasdf\", \"last_name\": \"MC asdfasdf\", \"cass_status\": \"APPROVED\", \"notes\": null, \"kcm_status\": \"DENIED\", \"employment_type\": \"flight_deck\", \"employee_id\": \"10598\", \"passport_id\": \"12341234\"}
]
```

When I deserialize this into a dynamic:

```
dynamic dsCrew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
```

dsCrew contains this:

```
{[
    {
        "passport_expiration": "2026-08-31",
        "first_name": "asdfasdf",
        "last_name": "MC asdfasdf",
        "cass_status": "APPROVED",
        "notes": null,
        "kcm_status": "DENIED",
        "employment_type": "flight_deck",
        "employee_id": "10598",
        "passport_id": "12341234"
    },
    {
        "passport_expiration": "2026-11-16",
        "first_name": "asdfasdf",
        "last_name": "BLasdf",
        "cass_status": "APPROVED",
        "notes": null,
        "kcm_status": "DENIED",
        "employment_type": "flight_deck",
        "employee_id": "14798",
        "passport_id": "12341234"
    },
    {
        "passport_expiration": "2025-05-05",
        "first_name": "sadfasdf",
        "last_name": "asdf",
        "cass_status": "APPROVED",
        "notes": "",
        "kcm_status": "DENIED",
        "employment_type": "flight_deck",
        "employee_id": "14838",
        "passport_id": "12341234"
    }
]}
```

It seems to have simply removed the escape characters, converted **some** nulls to Empty Strings, and wrapped the whole thing in an additional set of curly braces. It's like it deserialised into just a different serialized format.

In other SO questions, answers have suggested creating a class to deserialise into:

```
Deserialised_Crew dsCrew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Deserialised_Crew>(responseText);
```

But when I do that I get an exception:

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'CASS_KCM_Update.Deserialised_Crew' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() doesn't seem to think the responseText is valid JSON.  JSONLint.com says the JSON is valid.

I need a way to reference specific pieces of data:

`dsCrew[0].last_name` seems to reference the entire text inside the square brackets.  And I can't find any way to reference with any more specificity than that.  `dsCrew[0][1].last_name` won't work.  `dsCrew[0](1).last_name` is right out.

I need a way to reference the names and employee_id's in this response. I'm relatively new to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is probably just what you see in the debugger. That code should be fine.

Your second problem just involves deserializing to an array, since the JSON object is an array of crew:

```
Deserialised_Crew[] dsCrew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Deserialised_Crew[]>(responseText);
```

From there on, your code `dsCrew[0].last_name` should work as expected.

Comment: Some of you SO guys are really amazing!  I hope to get to your level, some day.  That actually did work, and I will mark as answer when the SO answer timeout expires.  ;-)